# Google Geochart dynamically update map from API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I have a google geochart that I'm plotting from JSON returned from an API.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Is it possible to dynamically update the map data from the API? Basically would like to increment the JSON returned in increments of 10 every 10 minutes and update the map. Is there any animation possible to do this as well?

Here's what I have so far but it only plots the data once

```js
function drawRegionsMap() {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country','Color'],
   <cfset i = 0>
   <cfloop array = "#dataTable#" index = "country">
   <cfset i ++>
   ['#country#',#i#] <cfif i neq ArrayLen(dataTable)>,</cfif>
   </cfloop>
 ]);

 var options = {
  legend:'none',
  colorAxis: {
   colors: ['##ff3333','##b30000']
  },
  tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
  backgroundColor:'##192b59'
 };

 var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

 chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  };
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's that markup you're using in your DataTable code? Not sure if that's a factor... but yes, you could for example do a javascript setTimeout() and change the data values using the DataTable's API. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that there are no animation options for GeoCharts, and you'll need to call `.draw()` on your chart again after you change the data.